# GeneXus - Container User Control + Abstract Layout

Tags: user-controls, genexus

I'm trying to develop a simple web user control, using the http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?5387,Hello+World+Container+User+Control, sample.

However, I need to work with a Responsive Table inside this control, so I need it to work with abstract layout, and when I drag the control to a layout, container is not created.

By the way, UC works fine in html mode.

Is it possible to do? What am I forgetting?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently user control containers in the layout mode is not supported.

What is your UC about? So we take it in consideration when we implement the feature

As a workaround you can use the control in html mode and add a layout control as a child to insert the responsive table.

Regards,
Cristian
Genexus Team

Comment: Hi Cristian, thanks for your answer.

Actually, what we want to do we can through Sections and CSS. But some structures demand more than 10 combinated different sections. With a contaier UC, we could potentiate this.

In a first step, what we would like to do was mixing Bootstrap css to use its controls. The most simple one is this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_panels.asp but there are plenty more.

As it's not yet supported, we have an issue with more examples, and we can provide more info if it's necessary.

Comment: You are right, you need user control containers to do that, we will implement it for our new version Salto, it is a missing feature we should have done from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the attention Cristian!
We will wait for this new feature at gx15!